# OOP: What should be the proper class design in this situation?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have an object  `guiObject` that comes from GUI. Based on its data fields I need to instantiate `domainObject` of proper class. It can either be `DomainClassA` or `DomainClassB`.

`DomainClassA` has one Integer contructor parameter `intParamA` (comes from `guiObject.fieldA`).

`DomainClassB` has one Integer contructor parameter `intParamB` (comes from `guiObject.fieldB`).

To solve this problem I made `AbstractFactory` that takes required fields from `guiObject`, instantiates either `DomainClassAFactory` or `DomainClassBFactory` with proper fields from `GuiClass` and retuns it. In turn, either of those factories `create()` properly instantiated `domainObject`.

But now, depending on `guiObject.fieldC` I need to alter `intParamA` and `intParamB` (i.e. decrease by 1) before instantiating `domainObject`. To achieve that I had to create separate factories for each different type of "parameter altering" for each `DomainClass` and then create separate abstract factories that produce correct factories. That sounds ugly and that looks ugly.

What should be the correct design?

Comment: I find this explanation highly confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you *need* all those layers, have a factory that interrogates the `guiObject` and returns the right type.

Over-analyzing leads to way too much stuff that most apps simply don't need. Add additional layers of abstraction only if they're strictly necessary. They're usually not.

Comment: +1 Any design problem can be solved by another level of indirection exception for the problem of too much indirection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally put all this logic in the original factory rather than trying to spread it out so much:

```
public DomainObj getDomainObj(GuiObject guiObject) {
    int param = guiObject.someField ? guiObject.intParamA : guiObject.intParamB;
    param = guiObject.fieldC ? param : param - 1;
    return guiObject.someField ? new DomainClassA(param) : new DomainClassB(param);
}
```